# Django keep dropdown selected language after page reload

Tags: css, django, forms, dropdown, reload

I have a form to change languages (3 languages so far) and it works except that when the page reloads, the content changes to the new language but the selected option from the dropdown is lost (instead shows default language). How can I keep the selected language after page reload? Any help is appreciated

```
 <form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="hidden" id="languageSwitcher" name="selected" value="{{ redirect_to}}">
            <select name ="language" id="languageField">
              {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
              {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
              {% for language in languages%}
              <option  value="{{language.code}}" {% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %} selected {% endif %}>
                {{language.name_local}} 
              </option>
              {% endfor %}
            </select>
          <input type="submit" id ="languageSwitcher" value="Change">
          </form>
```

Comment: Can we see your views.py?

Comment: I have included this in urls.py 
urlpatterns = [
    path('i18n/',include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

]. I didn't use any view associated to the language change form, I guess I am missing a lot here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the `LANGUAGE_CODE` variable in templates, you have to load `i18n` first.

Put this line of code at the top of your html template:

```
{% load i18n %}
```

Also, make sure `i18n` is enabled in your settings & context processors:

```
USE_I18N = True
# ...
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                # ...
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                # ...
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: I just add 'django.template.context_processors.i18n'  and it's working like a charm. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Gora no problem! If this solved your answer, you can press the “check mark” under the down arrow. This helps other people find the right answer if they have the same problem. Good luck!